# Excel: Count no. of times last value in a row occured

Tags: excel-2010

Am sorry am unable to paste the table here as my work laptop security doesn't let me. 
I have a row with multiple repetitive values eg columnB to BI containing 2s, 3s, 1s, and 3s again.
The value in last column is 3. I want to count for last how many columns was the value 3 before it changed to something else.

For example: if the row looks like

2 2 3 3 3 1 1 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 , then the answer I want is 5, because the last value is 2 and it was there for last 5 columns.

I hope it makes sense.

Thank you,
Parul.

Comment: So you are wanting to count how many times the last value is repeated going from right to left?

Comment: Yes, That's exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a UDF(User Defined Function) in VBA like this one:

```
Function CountLast(x As Range, y As Integer)

    Dim lColumn, count
    lColumn = x.Cells(x.count).Column 'Get last column in range x
    count = 0
    For i = lColumn To 0 Step -1      'Start with last column and work from right to left
        If Cells(1, i).Value <> y Then 'Compare value of each cell with the value provided in y and leave the loop if not found
            Exit For
        End If
        count = count + 1              'Counts how many times the value is found
    Next i

    CountLast = count                  'Returns the counted value
End Function
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
=CountLast(B1:BI1,BI1)
```

For the example data that you provide in your question I used:

```
=CountLast(A1:P1,P1)
```

and the resulting answer is 5

What is happening is that the UDF is finding the last cell in the range and then starting there is comparing it to the selected value that you also provide the function and working from right to left (`step -1`) then it counts as long as they match and in the end returns the counted value.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. Just one enhancement please, what if the value to be compared is text.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the value is `text` or anything else. This isn't checking for that it is just checking if the value you are looking for is in the cells next to it going from right to left. The part of the `function` that might need to change would be the declaration at the top. You can probably just take the `As Integer` out and leave it as just `y`. Then it won't matter what the `y` is.